# How to access JavaScript variable from PHP variable directly not as HTML tagged

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form name="from" id="from">
<input type="text" name="x" onkeyup="Get_Value()"/>
<input type="text" name="y" onkeyup="Get_Value()"/>
</form>                                                     

<script type="text/javascript">
      function Get_Value() {
         var x = Number(document.from.x.value);
         var y= Number(document.from.y.value);
         var total=x+y;
         document.getElementById("total").innerHTML =total;
        }
</script>
<?php
$total='<div id="total"></div>'; 
echo $total;
?>
```

When I execute this and put x=10, y=20 then it shows me 30 to the browser. Its fine.

When I save it the DB then it storing `<div id="total">30</div>`. But I need the 30 only.

Though the title of the question is a common one, I didn't found my answer.

What should I do now?

Comment: Where is the code that saves `<div id="30"></div>` to the database?

Comment: @George, `$total` contains the `<div id="total">30</div>`. That am storing later.

Comment: um, don't you mean `<div id="total">30</div>`...

Comment: Set it in a hidden field and post the data to the server...

Comment: you need to send the JS variable through an ajax call to a page (can be same page), only then php will know about the value of this JS variable or like @epascarello suggested use *hidden field* and then use `POST`

Comment: Can you really get the values you set with JS on the client side with PHP. I suppose you had to use a form and send it to PHP or use Ajax for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want send data from PHP that would be accessable in JS, then you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function Get_Value(x, y) {
          var total=x+y;
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML =total;
      }

      Get_Value(<?php echo 10; ?>, <?php echo 20; ?>);
</script>
```

If you have, any variable , then replace `echo 10` with your choice.

Comment: you are checking it in `javascript` scope, but I need to access it from php segment.

Comment: The other way is not possible. Then you need send AJAX to your server, with your value.